# Generating python data structures from parsed text without eval()

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a tool to generate datastructures from a text config.  I use`pyparsing` to parse the commands...

**CONFIG FILE:**

```
add Iteration name = "Cisco 10M/half"
    append Observation name = "packet loss"
        assign Observation results_text = 0.0
        assign Observation results_bool = True
        append DataPoint
            assign DataPoint metric = txpackets
            assign DataPoint units = packets
```

**PYPARSING COMMANDS**

```
['add', 'Iteration', ['name', 'Cisco 10M/half']]
['append', 'Observation', ['name', 'packet loss']]
['assign', 'Observation', ['results_text', '0']]
['assign', 'Observation', ['results_bool', 'True']]
['append', 'DataPoint']
['assign', 'DataPoint', ['metric', 'txpackets']]
['assign', 'DataPoint', ['units', 'packets']]
```

The first column is a command verb, and the second is the name of a class I've already defined.

Right now, the only solution I can come up with for building the resultant data structure looks like this:

```
if cmd == 'add':
    obj = eval('%s()' % (txtobj))  # Create the TestData object
```

In the case of the first command, it needs to call `Iteration()`, which is the name of a class I have imported into the parser.

Is there a way to build the classes from the text config without resorting to `eval()`?  If so, how would you do it?

**EDIT:**

Sven's answer assumed I already had the classes created, but dynamically creating classes was actually part of the problem.

This is how I can create a new class named 'Child' dynamically, assuming a parent class named Parent is already in my code...

```
>>> child_name = "Child"
>>> child_parents = (Parent,)
>>> child body = """
def __init__(self, arg1):
    # Initialization for the Child class
    self.foo = do_something(arg1)
"""
>>> child_dict = {}
>>> exec(child_body, globals(), child_dict)
>>> childobj = type(child_name, child_parents, child_dict)
>>> childobj.__name__
'Child'
>>> childobj.__bases__
(<type 'object'>,)
>>> # Instantiating the new Child object...
>>> childinst = childobj()
>>> childinst
<__main__.Child object at 0x1c91710>
>>>
```

If I need to create a global or local variable dynamically, I should avoid `globals()` and use a `dict()`...

```
>>> vars = {}
>>> varname = 'foo'
>>> vars[varname] = True
>>>
```

In a comment, I also asked how I could generate dynamic keywords for method calls... 
such as:

```
eval('log.append(%s._replace(%s = val))' % (objtxt, key)
```

The solution is to use Sven's answer (below) for the class instance, and a [mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092336/a-better-way-than-eval-when-translating-keyword-arguments-in-querysets-python/5092385#5092385) (i.e. dict) in the method args...

```
classes = dict((c.__name__, c) for c in [Iteration,Observation,DataPoint])
# ...
obj = classes[txtobj]()
log.append(obj._replace(**{"%s" % key: val}))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from your `eval()` call, it looks like the classes you are trying to instantiate are in your current global scope.  You can simply look them up yourself and create an instance:

```
obj = globals()[txtobj]()
```

Note that this will call any global object named by `txtobj`, so you should not use this for untrusted data.

It might be better to create your own dictionary of allowed classes:

```
classes = dict((c.__name__, c) for c in [Iteration,Observation,DataPoint])
# ...
obj = classes[txtobj]()
```

Comment: Thank you, I am importing into global ns with `from this import that`... how should I write this if I have them in non-global namespace?

Comment: @Mike: See the edited version of the post.  It would also be possible to use `locals()` for the local scope, but the dictionary approach is probably better.

Comment: One related question if you don't mind... I also have this `eval()` as well... `eval('log.append(obj._replace(%s = val))' % (obj, key)`... you provided a solution for `obj`, but how can I call the `_replace()` method using a keyword as a variable (`key`)?

Comment: @Mike: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092336/a-better-way-than-eval-when-translating-keyword-arguments-in-querysets-python/5092385#5092385).